# Terraform module in github private repo

Tags: git, github, terraform

I am trying to use my private git repo as source for the terraform modules.

ssh public key has been copied over to github.

Tried following options as source but nothing worked:

- git::git@github.com:/terraform-modules//sub-dir
- github.com/terraform-modules//sub-dir
- git@github.com:/terraform-modules//sub-dir
- git::https://MACHINE-USER:MACHINE-PASS@github.com/terraform-modules//sub-dir
- git::https://github.com//terraform-modules.git//subdir
- https://GIT_HUB_PAT@github.com/terraform-modules.git//subdir

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Referring to Private Github repos section on the following link didn't help either.
https://github.com/alibaba/terraform-provider/blob/master/vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform/website/docs/modules/sources.html.markdown

Private GitHub Repos
If you need Terraform to fetch modules from private GitHub repos, you must provide Terraform with credentials to authenticate as a user with read access to those repos.

If you run Terraform only on your local machine, you can specify the module source as an SSH URI (like git@github.com:hashicorp/example.git) and Terraform will use your default SSH key to authenticate.

If you use Terraform Enterprise, you can use SSH URIs. You'll need to add an SSH private key to your organization and assign it to any workspace that fetches modules from private repos. See the Terraform Enterprise docs about SSH keys for cloning modules.

If you need to run Terraform on a remote machine like a CI worker, you either need to write an SSH key to disk and set the GIT_SSH_COMMAND environment variable appropriately during the worker's provisioning process, or ***create a GitHub machine user with read access to the repos in question and embed its credentials into the modules' source parameters:
module "private-infra" {
  source = "git::https://MACHINE-USER:MACHINE-PASS@github.com/org/privatemodules//modules/foo"
}***
Note that Terraform does not support interpolations in the source parameter of a module, so you must hardcode the machine username and password if using this method.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

1. Set up your ssh keys; make sure that your `~/.ssh/config` file has a block like this:

```
Host USERNAME.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

2. Add this to your `.tf` file:

```
module "name_of_module" {
  source = "git@USERNAME.github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git//SUBDIR"
  ...
}
```

Comment: I would also follow [this](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection). However, official [docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/sources#github) (which works for me) say `git@github.com:my_owner/my_module.git`

Answer (score 6):

Things needed:

- A GitHub machine account (Note: This is not much different from a regular GitHub account functionally; it is referred to as "machine" based on the intended usage).
  See [machine users](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/overview/managing-deploy-keys#machine-users).
- An ssh key. Note: I used RSA. Example on how to generate one:

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
```

- Associate the public key with the GitHub machine account.
  See [adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).
- Then, either in your particular repo OR as an organizational secret, add the *private* ssh key in GitHub.

Note: If you configure the organizational secret to be available to specific repos,
be sure to specify the repo that has the Terraform code that you are attempting to import.

- Then, in your GitHub Action yaml file, add the code that adds the *private* ssh key to the runner's ssh agent,
  to be able to clone the Terraform module that is in a private GitHub repo. Example:

```yaml
      - name: Terraform Init
        id: init
        run: terraform init
        env:
          GIT_SSH_COMMAND: "echo '${{ secrets.ORG_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY }}' > id_rsa
          && ssh-keyscan github.com > known_hosts
          && chmod 600 id_rsa known_hosts
          && ssh -i ./id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts"

      - name: Terraform Plan
        id: plan
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        run: terraform plan -no-color
        continue-on-error: true
        env:
          GIT_SSH_COMMAND: "echo '${{ secrets.ORG_PRIVATE_SSH_KEY }}' > id_rsa
          && ssh-keyscan github.com > known_hosts
          && chmod 600 id_rsa known_hosts
          && ssh -i ./id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=./known_hosts"
```

Reference/Credit:
https://github.com/hashicorp/setup-terraform/issues/33

Note: There appears to be many ways to do such things when googling but I labored over this for weeks trying the various options
and ultimately was able to do it with this AND I understood how it worked. :) I encourage feedback.

Comment: Hey, I was wondering in which cases this works? Like say I want to import a module from a private repo, and I am running the code from a VM where I have not set up any other credentials (no ssh-key or PAT), could adding this github action let me load the private module? Because I have been trying it out and I cannot get it working yet.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me

```
module "name_of_module" {
  source = "git::https://<user>:<pat>@github.com/folder/terraform-azure-core-resource-group.git"
  ...
}
```

Comment: this puts your pat in your code. anyone with access to the terraform code will then have access to the terraform module being invoked

Answer (score 4):

I will not go for SSH, and none of the above work for me in the CI for private repository

```
git config --global url."https://${USER}:${USER_READONLY_TOKEN}@github.com/my_orgnization".insteadOf "https://github.com/my_orgnization"
```

[image]

Make sure the token is read-only privileges and organizations `my_orgnization` name is correct

```
      - run:
          name: remote backend
          command: |
            git config --global url."https://${USER}:${USER_READONLY_TOKEN}@github.com/my_orgnization".insteadOf "https://github.com/my_orgnization"
            terraform init
```

Answer (score 3):

I recently solved this problem.

For your local develop you can continue to use the SSH git url, as follows:

```
module <moduleName> {
  source                   = "git::git@github.com:<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git//<modulePath>?ref=<moduleTag>" 
  ...
}
```

For the Github actions workflow you can switch to https url by overriding the git config url. The workflow job will look as follows:

```
jobs:
  <jobName>:
      env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The GITHUB_TOKEN is available as a secrets to talk with Github repositories. Ensure repo setting for token permissions as specified here : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication

Once you have the environment variable for the token (GH_TOKEN) here. Then you can override the git url config as follows to ask git to use https url instead of ssh url as used by terraform code.

```
git config --global url."https://oauth2:$GH_TOKEN@github.com/<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git"
```

Now, `terraform init` should work in the github workflow without any need to ssh key setup.

Here is more details here: [Terraform Git Clone does not seems to work with GITHUB_TOKEN but works when used a PAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73684084/terraform-git-clone-does-not-seems-to-work-with-github-token-but-works-when-used)

Answer (score 2):

Tested on bitbucket. It should be the same on github:

```
source = "git::https://@bitbucket.com/mycompany/my-project.git"
```

Comment: This gave the same error. remote: Not Found
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/terraform-azure-modules.git/' not found

Comment: Can you paste the full line you are using here

Comment: source                       = "git::https://@github.com/org/terraform-azure-modules.git//storageaccount"

Comment: any luck on this?

Answer (score 2):

in our organisation we were also using terrafom modules created in the private git repos and it worked locally but in the github action it was real pain to resolve. here is how i resolve it.
You need user account that is member of the repo and has the git access token associated with it and change your workflow plan file as below:

```
jobs:
  plan:
    environment: production
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: New Relic terraform plan
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: terraform plan
        uses: dflook/terraform-apply@v1.15.0
        env:
          TERRAFORM_HTTP_CREDENTIALS: github.com/DigitalInnovation=<userName>:${{ secrets.GIT_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 2):

[@Magnus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66617272/7069108) answer is great. But for me, his 2nd step cannot be done because it is not my code, thus I cannot arbitrarily modify the source code (for the 2nd step). So here's my overall solution:

1. Follow [this steps](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) to make sure everything has been configured correctly
2. Make sure that your `~/.ssh/config` has these lines:

```
Host YOUR_USERNAME.github.com
    HostName github.com
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

For example, mine is:

```
Host YOUR_USERNAME.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

3. Run these commands:

```
git config --global url."ssh://git@YOUR_USERNAME.github.com".insteadOf https://github.com
```

To verify this step, you can run `cat  ~/.gitconfig` and see if the output contains these lines:

```
[url "ssh://git@YOUR_USERNAME.github.com"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com
```

4. Try to run `terraform init` and see if it runs normally (no auth problem).
   If not, try to run:

```
git config --global url."ssh://git@YOUR_USERNAME.github.com".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com
```

and rerun `terraform init`.

### Note:

- Replace all `YOUR_USERNAME` with your actual Github username
- If you run `terraform init` and it asks you to input your GitHub username and password, there should be a problem in your configuration. My configurations above expect `terraform init` **not to ask** for your GitHub username and password.

Comment: I just tested this but using `YOUR_USERNAME.github.com` didn't work for me.
I had to skip the `YOUR_USERNAME` part and then it just worked flawlessly.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using a github token with `git config --global url."https://${GH_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com` to replace the ssh urls with https, is what ended up making `terraform get` work for me when it was run from inside a docker container

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a Gitlab CI pipeline, you can just adapt your config with:

```
before_script:
- git config --global url."https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab.com".insteadOf https://gitlab.com
```