# Terraform Git Clone does not seems to work with GITHUB_TOKEN but works when used a PAT

Tags: github, terraform, github-actions

I am adding a Github actions workflow to execute terraform commands as part of the pipeline.

The terraform code refers refer to terraform modules from another repo as follows.

```
module <moduleName> {
  source                   = "git::git@github.com:<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git//<modulePath>?ref=<moduleTag>" 
  ...
}
```

This will lead to fetching the code from given tag during `terraform init` command execution.

To ensure that https url is used instead of SSH git url. I am overriding the git config url as follows.

```
git config --global url."https://oauth2:$GITHUB_TOKEN@github.com/<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git"
```

But GITHUB_TOKEN does not allow git clone and this fails with the following error:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for
'https://github.com/<repoName>/<moduleRepo>.git/'
```

I also tried adding permission to the workflow for repositories as follows:

```
permissions:
  repository-projects: read
```

The repo setting for action is set to : `Allow all actions and reusable workflows`

**If I change the GITHUB_TOKEN with my PAT with `repo` permissions, then the workflow works without any issues.**

Please let me know how to configure GITHUT_TOKEN with required permissions. I want to make it work with GITHUB_TOKEN rather than PAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I was able to figure out the issue. The GITHUB_TOKEN is made available to the Github Action workflow as a secret and not as an environment variable.

The issue was I was treating it as an environment variable and using it as such, which lead to the error.

I changed the workflow as follows to use it as a secret.

```
jobs:
  <jobName>:
      env:
        GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

I updated the git config as follows to use the token properly:

```
git config --global url."https://oauth2:$GH_TOKEN@github.com/<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git".insteadOf "ssh://git@github.com/<orgName>/<moduleRepo>.git"
```

The workflow now seems to work properly.

The usage is documented here: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api#authentication-example-for-github-actions

Adding my answer here to help others facing similar issue.